# boost::odeint deduction/substitution failure

Tags: c++, templates, boost, odeint

How should I change my code in order to properly overload `vector_space_norm_inf` for implementing custom state type?

```
template<typename T>
class Traits{
public:
  typedef T value_t;
  typedef complex<value_t> scalar_t;
  typedef vector<scalar_t> state_t;
}

using namespace boost;
using namespace numeric;
using namespace odeint;

template<typename T>
struct vector_space_norm_inf<typename Traits<T>::state_t>{
  typedef typename Traits<T>::value_t result_type;
  typedef typename Traits<T>::scalar_t scalar_t;
  typedef typename Traits<T>::state_t state_t;

  result_type operator()(const state_t& x) const{
    auto comparator=[](const scalar_t& x1, const scalar_t& x2){
      return std::abs(x1)<std::abs(x2);
    };
    auto result=std::max_element(x.begin(),x.end(),comparator);
    result_type maxElement=std::abs(*result);
    return maxElement;
  }
};
```

The problem is that I try to deduce template parameter from dependent scope. I understand that this is not possible and I'm asking here for some idea how to change my code in order to avoid it.

Comment: Do you want to specialize for everything that has a trait class?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use your `Traits` class template - use what you want `state_t` to be directly:

```
namespace boost { namespace numeric { namespace odeint {
    template<typename T>
    struct vector_space_norm_inf<vector<complex<T>>> {
        ...
    };
}}}
```